# Where did the the $\delta(0)$ go?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, commutator, dirac-delta-distributions, second-quantization

I am reading my notes for a lecture on quantum field theory. For some example of a 1d system with spatial coordinate $x$ and for a wave with frequency $\omega$, it starts with defining field operators which obey the boson commutation relations:

$$ [\psi(x,\omega),\psi^\dagger(x',\omega')] =\delta(x-x')\delta(\omega-\omega') \tag{1}$$

Later we consider the equal-position commutator

$$ [\psi(x,\omega),\psi^\dagger(x,\omega')] = \delta(\omega-\omega') \tag{2}$$

If I see it correctly, then there should be another factor $\delta(0)$ on the right hand side. Where did this factor disappear? Nothing is mentioned regarding this in the example. I have also seen a few papers online which similarly let $\delta(0)$ expressions disappear. If I understand it correctly, then $\delta(0)$ is not even well-defined.

Unfortunately, I could not find the link to the original document. But I have found something similar [in here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.01958). Consider equation (23) and compare with equation (54a):

The first reads

$$ [\psi_\mu(z), \psi^\dagger_{\mu'}(z')] = \delta_{\mu,\mu'}\delta(z-z')\tag{23} $$

and the latter

$$ [a_j(z_m,\omega), a_{j'}^\dagger(z_m,\omega)] = \delta_{j,j'}\delta(\omega-\omega') .\tag{54a}$$

Granted, it is not immediately clear that that is the same as in my case, but it looks similar.

Comment: The thing which usually makes a dirac delta disappear as you may know is integration. I think it is implicit that in moving from the first equation to the second one an integration over the variable $x'$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ has taken place.

Comment: To make a full response, I believe the context is essential. Can you please put the link to the article/lecture notes ? If I am correct about the context, they probably work in finite volume so $\delta(0)$ is proportional to $1/V$ and doesn't cause problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic That was from an online document. But also see my edit. (I mean technically they were lecture notes online)

Comment: @emirsezik Please see my edit

Comment: Making sense of this is as much as exercise in dimensional analysis as in anything else. The second equation either defines fields differently or has an invisible integration over $x$... but the latter option makes no sense, for reasons you can probably spot.

Comment: The Hamiltonian of a free QFT has a positive $\delta(0)$ for bosons and a negative $\delta(0)$ for fermions. Provided you are not studying gravity, only changes in energy are meaningful and it is valid to renormalize this away.